# Python 3.6 thread switching between two operations

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I have following pseudo-code:

```
global my_list = [1, 2, 3]
def thread1():
    my_list.append(10)
def thread2():
    my_list = my_list[1:]
```

Let's say thread2 is executing. Is it possible that it will be switched to thread1 in-between my_list slicing and assigning to my_list?
What are operations that are never interrupted by context switch?

Comment: no it's not possible because of python GIL.

Comment: But is it possible that GIL will be released between these 2 operations?

Comment: not possible with pure Python code with CPython implementation. There are other implementations where that could be possible. Check duplicate links, the info is there.

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice duplicate

Comment: yeah, I think you have to refresh for that. Annoying isn't it? have a good read.